# Make a delay in reading php codes

Tags: javascript, php

I want to make a delay in my PHP codes to alert my Javascript code and then run header function in the bottom.

I tried to implement my ideas with sleep function in php . But when i tried it , all of the program sleeps for seconds .

```php
<?php

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_FILES);
echo "</pre>" ;

$randNum = rand(0,999);
$fileAd = "Images\User".$randNum ;
$mkFile = mkdir($fileAd);
$fileDir = __DIR__ ;
$uploadFile = $fileDir. "\\" . $fileAd . "\\" . $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadFile)){
    echo "<script>
    alert(\"Thanks\");
    </script>";



}


$contentFile = $fileDir . "\\" . $fileAd . "\\" . "User" . $randNum . ".txt" ;
$str = "" ;

foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        $str .= "$key : ";
        $str .= implode(" , ",$value).PHP_EOL;

    }else {
        $str .= "$key : $value".PHP_EOL;
    }
}

file_put_contents($contentFile,$str);

header("Location: sugFuncs.php");

?>
```

Comment: PHP is single threaded, if you pause it, it will pause everything. PHP is completely executed before _anything_ prints on the page, this includes your javascript. Also, you cannot set headers after anything has been printed on the page, so you couldn't echo any JavaScript (or anything) and then change the headers.

Comment: you can turn your php into "multithreaded" application with pcntl_fork() and do a sleep inside of fork'ed process. (term multithreaded is not very suitable technically speaking, but it gets the point across)

Comment: I want to alert something when i received data from user.I'm a beginner in php and I'm learnin it yet .

Answer (score 0):

It is because you sleep at server-side. The server would need to tell the client to sleep instead of sleeping on its own, like:

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'],$uploadFile)){
    echo "<script>
    setTimeout(() => alert(\"Thanks\"), 5000);
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but it doesn't work correctly yet .

Comment: @Omidgh How is it working and what would you expect instead?

Comment: I want to receive data from user and then thank him\her by an alert , after that return to register page by header function in php.